# How to test if game center is available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

I just implemented game center support in my app like it's described here [How To Make A Simple Multiplayer Game with Game Center Tutorial: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12).

It is realized as a singleton. In my app delegate:

```
    // At the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching, right before 
    // the last line that calls runWithScene:
    [[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
```

A little overview over the methods and attributes:

```
@interface GCHelper : NSObject {
    BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
    BOOL userAuthenticated;
}

@property (assign, readonly) BOOL gameCenterAvailable;

+ (GCHelper *)sharedInstance;
- (void) authenticateLocalUser;

@end
```

Since there is now reference to the GCHelper in my app delegate I wonder how to actually test in an other class (where I submit score) if game center is available.

**How do I get the singleton instance of GCHelper in another class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see how I get the instance of singleton class in another class :

//DataClass.h

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject {    

int i;   

}    
@property(nonatomic,assign)int i;    
+(DataClass*)getInstance;    
@end
```

//DataClass.m

```
@implementation DataClass    
@synthesize i;    
static DataClass *instance =nil;    
+(DataClass *)getInstance    
{    
@synchronized(self)    
{    
    if(instance==nil)    
{    

    instance= [DataClass new];    
}    
}    
return instance;    
}
```

Now in your view controller you need to call this method as :

```
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];  
obj.i= // whatever you want;
```

This variable will be accessible to every view controller. You just have to create an instance of Data class.